# Understanding formulas for the sampling distribution of the mean

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, central-limit-theorem

In the passage below, what does $k_c$ mean, and why (in "$σ_0/\sqrt n$") is $\sigma$ being divided by the square root of $n$? I got this form the book *Principles of statistical inference*.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These concepts are not really specific to frequentism. $k_c^*$ just means that $1-2c$ of the mass of the standard normal lies in the range $(-k_c^*, k_c^*)$; in this case, about $95\%$ of the mass lies within $(-1.96,1.96)$. The frequentist interpretation comes when you consider a result within that range to be "typical" or "expected" under the null hypothesis, while a result outside that range is unlikely (in this example, it occurs $<5\%$ of the time) and thus evidence against the null hypothesis.

The second notation, $\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}$ is just the standard error of the sample mean under the usual assumptions and further that the samples are iid with variance $\sigma_0^2$. This is a basic result and there is nothing specifically frequentist about this, except the assumption under the null hypothesis that the variance is $\sigma_0^2$.